# Django: associating a user with model instance

Tags: django, many-to-many

Let's say that I have a model that handles recipes, and I want to allow users to input their own recipes via a form. I then want to associate that recipe entry with the user ID of the user who inputted it. My guess is that my model would look something like this:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    creator = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.creator
```

Is that correct? And if I created a model form, it would look something like this:

```
class RecipeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
```

But how would I go about automatically passing the user information to the Recipe model upon submission? Would this take place in my view?

My current view is like this:

```
def recipe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST) #if POST method, bound form to POST data
        if form.is_valid():         
            form.save()
    else:
        form = RecipeForm() #unbound form.
    recipe_list = Recipe.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('forms/recipes.html',
        {'form': form, 'recipe_list': recipe_list},
        context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

How would I set the user to the model before saving it?

Comment: You probably want a normal 1-1 foreign key, instead of ManyToMany

Comment: My thinking behind the ManyToMany is that I potentially would like users to be able to share recipes. Many users could have access to a recipe, and each user could have many recipes.

Comment: ManyToMany means one recipie can have many users; I don't think that's what you want. What you want is "this recipie belongs to userA", which is what the normal `models.ForeignKey` will do for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your view would need to set the user on the recipe model before saving it.

Comment: That makes sense. How would I alter my view to set the user on the recipe model before saving it? I posted what I have so far.

Comment: Pass `commit=False`, assign to `creator`, and save the model.

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit:

*You should accept Ignacio's answer, since he added it in the comment.*

Here is how you would add your user:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def recipe(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST) #if POST method, bound form to POST data
        if form.is_valid():         
            obj = form.save(commit=False) # don't save to DB
            obj.creator = request.user # adds the user
            obj.save()
    else:
        form = RecipeForm() #unbound form.
    recipe_list = Recipe.objects.all()
    return render(request,'forms/recipes.html',
        {'form': form, 'recipe_list': recipe_list})
```

Comment: Burhan, you're awesome! thanks. I didn't know how to pass variables to specific fields in the view. Can I ask why you need to form.save(commit=False) beforehand? Couldn't you just do form.creator = request.user and only then do form.save()?

Comment: I see why now, after reading this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: Before `form.save()`, `form` is the ModelForm instance, after `form.save()`, you get the an instance from the model (in other words, an object from the db). You then add to the model's instance before saving it to the db. See [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) for more information.

Comment: Burhan - I just noticed that you altered the last line, removing the "render_to_response". Can you explain why you did that?

Comment: The [`render`](http://django.me/render) shortcut makes it easier to send the correct context.